# Visual Studio Intellisense is not working for TagHelpers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, tag-helpers

I am not able to get Intellisense to work for my Tag Helpers in Visual Studio. I have started a project from scratch and set up the dependencies and frameworks in the project.json file as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

Note that the Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor package is included. Based on the docs and other questions that have been answered on here, this should be sufficient to get Intellisense working for the tag helpers. Also, when I create a Web Application using the standard template in Visual Studio, the Intellisense works fine, so I am not sure what I am missing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same issue, would love it if someone could shed some light on this. However, for the template site, it also isn't working for me.

Comment: Do you have an appropriate @addTagHelper inclusion in your views?

Comment: Yes I have an appropriate @addTagHelper inclusion in my views...the views were rendering fine, the only issue was that I wasn't getting any Intellisense while I was coding. That said, the Intellisense is working for me now, and I believe it started working after I restarted Visual Studio, so I recommend that people try to restart the IDE if they are having issues.